# Why does Beautiful Soup return this random string?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse a web page to get a brief overview from a stock.  From seekingalpha, the HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="company_description_mini_text">
<span style='white-space: pre-line;'>Provectus Biopharmaceuticals Inc is a development-stage pharmaceutical company. It develops, licenses, and sells pharmaceutical products for oncology and dermatology indications.</span>
</div>
```

and for my code, I have this:

```
getSummary = soup1.find_all('div', class_='company_description_mini_text')
print getSummary[0].text[100]
```

However, what is returned is simply the letter 'e'.  True to form, there is only that single element in the list.  If anyone could show me where I went wrong, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You'll get an attribute error, actually.

Comment: Could you please explain why?

Comment: `getSummary` is a result set, not a single element. The result list has no `title` attribute.

Comment: Oh, duh.  That's a typo.  It's supposed to be getSummary[0].text[100].  Regardless, the code still doesn't work.

Comment: what do you want it to return instead?

Comment: **What** doesn't work. What did you expect to get instead? `text` doesn't return a list, it returns *one string* containing all contained text in the element.

Answer (score 2):

`text` returns a string, and indexing into that string gives you an individual character; `e` is the character at index 100 of the text; you can get other individual characters, or use slicing:

```
>>> getSummary[0].text
u'\nProvectus Biopharmaceuticals Inc is a development-stage pharmaceutical company. It develops, licenses, and sells pharmaceutical products for oncology and dermatology indications.\n'
>>> getSummary[0].text[100]
u'e'
>>> getSummary[0].text[0]
u'\n'
>>> getSummary[0].text[:20]
u'\nProvectus Biopharma'
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one `<div class="company_description_mini_text">` your `html` that you are scraping, then, there is no need to use `find_all()`. You can use `find()` method.

```
getSummary = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': "company_description_mini_text"})
```

Here `getSummary` is a `Tag` type object. and you can directly apply `.text` on it. like,

```
print getSummary.text
```

Now `getSummary.text` returns you a `unicode` object. And if you print `getSummary.text`[100]
then it will give you the `100th` value of the string.